# Does Treebeard have any children?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, ents

In the books Treebeard laments the ents' loss of their entwives -which is why they can't have children **anymore**.  However the way Treebeard describes the entwives, it seems that they  (ents and entwives ) spent **some time** together before they parted.  Now when they spent time together they must have had children - if not how can there be so many ents?

Treebeard is said to be the **oldest** ent. If Treebeard is like Adam, then all ents are descended from him, like how all men are descended from Adam! However this might not be completely true because

> Treebeard is the oldest ent **alive**

This suggests that Treebeard might not be the first ent. But in that case, if Treebeard is son of the oldest ent and former ent leader (which is why he is the leader of Ents) he must have had children!  Adam isn't the direct father of all of us! Adam's sons can be considered as our fathers because we are descended from them! Similarly for Treebeard.

So did Treebeard have any  (ent) children  ?

Interesting note : The female ents are called 'Entwives'. Now a wife is a woman who is married to a man. This suggests that Entwives might have been married to Ents. Though this simply might be a blooper.

Comment: We must also ask : Is Treebeard the first Ent  ?

Comment: Again, Tolkien doesn't cover this rather pointless detail because it is of no concern to him, his stories or his legendarium. However logic would suggest yes. As the oldest, he would most likely have had entlings

Comment: @Edlothiad Point less detail  !? I on the other hand consider this to be very important. It might be a defining feature of Treebeard

Comment: Whether or not he sprouted entlings is defining, certainly not from the character presented in the works.

Comment: How do you consider it important? What changes *in the story* depending on whether Treebeard had offspring or not?

Comment: @chepner you should see the Harry Potter questions in this site.

Comment: @Edlothiad This is obviously a legitimate question and your judgemental approach helps no one.

Comment: @TheMadHatter I think I seem to remember entwives are not calling themselves entwives.

Comment: @C.Koca It certainly is a legitimate question, it's just one that Tolkien felt no need to answer. He himself was _never_ interested in all the genealogies and the breakdown of society and so forth. He was a philologist first and foremost, his universe provides a physical presence to his languages and the derivations thereof. That's important to remember and it certainly weighs on the quality of a question within the legendarium.

Comment: @C.Koca the entwives don't call themselves entwives but it's the ents who do so

Comment: @Edlothiad - The word _entings_ does not include the letter "L".

Comment: @Edlothiad, Tolkien was certainly interested in genealogies, as he mapped out hobbit, elf, some dwarf, and some human genealogies. But none for Ents that I know of.